# NGINX proxy_pass setup fails when adding a location for expiring file types

Tags: nginx, wordpress, proxypass

When adding the following to my Nginx config server block, the /blog/ location starts 404'ing all file types referenced.  What is the correct way to leverage the expires directive and continue to keep proxy_pass working fully?  Is there a way to adjust the regex to say all these file types except within the /blog/* directories?

```
location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|pdf)$ {
    expires 7d;
}
```

Below are the other location references in the server block.  If I take out the expires 7d; everything works fine.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location /blog/ {
    proxy_pass https://blog.domain.com/;
    proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}

error_page 404 /index.php;

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
# browser caching of static assets
location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|pdf)$ {
    expires 7d;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example:

```
map $uri $expires {
    default off;
    ~\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|pdf)$ 7d;
}

server {
    ...
    location / {
        expires $expires;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    ...
}
```

With this approach you can specify dirrerent expire time for different file types:

```
map $uri $expires {
    default off;
    ~\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$ 30d;
    ~\.(css|js|pdf)$ 7d;
}
```

Another way is to set expire time by content type of request body, example from [official documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#expires):

```
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default         off;
    application/pdf 42d;
    ~image/         max;
}

server {
    ...
    expires $expires;
    ...
}
```